# How to start reading .txt file from a specific line?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I have a text file of the following format

```
x     y
3     8
mz    int
200.1    3
200.3    4
200.5    5
200.7    2
```

and so on. Now in this file, I want to save the x and y values in two different variables and the mz and int values in two different arrays. How do I read such a file in Java.

Comment: https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/Programming_Test/blob/master/network_prog_Java/FileReaderExamples/src/FileParseTestII.java

Answer (score 0):

Is the format fixed? If yes, then you can skip first line, read next line, split it and assign to two variables.

Then you can skip the next line and split each of next lines and assign to array.

Comment: Yes. The format is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = null;
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\file.txt"));
            int i = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                i ++ ;
                if(i > 3){
                    String temp1 = line.split("    ")[0];
                    String temp2 = line.split("    ")[1];
                    list1.add(temp1);
                    list2.add(temp2);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
    }
}
```

BTW:here is [10 golden rules of asking questions in the OpenSource community](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/03/09/asking-community-questions/).